# Unspecified Pronouns, use of だから in a sentence

Tags: translation

I was trying to translate these song lyrics:

いつか気づくかもしれないけど
間違いだらけの 僕だから

I was thinking that this meant either "Someday, you might notice me, who is prone to mistakes/whose life is full of mistakes." Or, possibly, "Someday, I might notice that my life is full of mistakes." I can't decide which pronoun fits better. But either way, I can't get the because (だから) to fit. "Someday, I/you might notice, because my life is full of mistakes" doesn't make sense to me, but I don't know any other meaning for だから.

Please help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

だから means because.
And it implies that the fact that "you are full of mistakes" is the cause of something.
Having more context/previous sentence/next sentence would be needed for an accurate understanding.

As it stands, all that can be understood is :
**[you/I] might someday notice [...] but, because I am full of mistakes [...]**

Comment: I believe the implicit/abbreviated conclusion could be "because I'm full of mistakes, I can't notice"

Comment: Okay, so in short, "I/you might notice it someday, but because I am full of mistakes, [I/you can't]." Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @Smoothie Only I can be full of mistakes. Not "you".

Answer (score 0):

Here, the function of だから is the same as you would expect.

So 「いつか気づくかもしれないけど」← The reason for this is 「僕」

That is why it is written as 「僕だから」

間違いだらけ here describes 僕.

> [I?] might notice it someday, I who am full of mistakes...

--

P.S. It might be better to not ask the question in context of translation.